# How to connect my cli app to a website using websocket securely

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket, command-line-interface

**What I want to achieve**

I have a website built using react and a command line app built using python, which the user will download on their machine.

What I wanna do is, when the user runs the python code through terminal, the code should open up the website on their browser and establish a websocket connection with the website.

Now the user can enter messages in an input in the website and these messages will be sent back, in real time, to the command line app which will write the messages into a file on the user's system.

How do I make sure the only the website opened by the user connects to the terminal, how do I re-establish the connection if the browser was closed accidentally?

**My approach**

My approach is that on running the python script in terminal, it would request a socket connection from an external server, which will return a room code in response.

Then the python script will open the website with room code as query string, which the website will use to request the external server to be added to the socket room with the terminal and then the apps can go back and forth with messages

Is this approach recommended and secure enough?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah your solution sounds like it will work fine so long as traffic is sent over wss and the room code is unguessable.

A pretty common pattern for sending out websocket messages is to store a list of connected client IDs. When a new message comes in loop through all the client IDs that should receive the message and send it to each of them.

So to handle the re-connect just add the new client ID to the database for that room.

---

I know you mentioned python but here is some Typescript code using AWS API Gateway that does that. Hopefully it can help you a little:

```js
    /**
     * Sends a websocket message to all connected clients
     */
    sendMessage: async (message: string, room: string) => {
        const connections = await database.getAllClientsInRoom(room);

        const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
            apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
            endpoint: process.env.WS_ENDPOINT,
        });

        const requests = connections.map(async ({ connectionID }) => {
            await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionID, Data: message }).promise();
            console.log(`Message sent to: ${connectionID}`);
        });

        return await Promise.all(requests);
    },
```